# Bookdown reproducibility

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, bookdown

I'm working on a large scale bookdown project.  The source is in a git repo, we have two authors and various computers.  We've discovered that we cannot reproduce the book - each machine builds it slightly differently, resulting in slightly different paginations and ultimately in a variation of 2-3 pages length in a 500+ page book.

As a concrete example, I've built the book on two Macs with packages all updated.  Specifically:

- R 4.0.5
- pandoc 2.13
- bookdown 0.22
- rmarkdown 2.8
- markdown 1.1
- knitr 1.33
- styler 1.4.1

I can't explain why we're getting different output.  We are getting different .md files, so it seems like it's something in the bookdown/markdown/knitr part of the toolchain. Here's a couple of lines of it:

```
19c19
< {\centering \includegraphics[height=3in]{images/facecone} 
---
> {\centering \includegraphics[width=9.17in,height=3in]{images/facecone} 
684c684
< mean(replicate(10000, t.test(rnorm(10, 0, 1), mu = 1)$p.value < .05))
---
> mean(replicate(10000, t.test(rnorm(10,0,1), mu = 1)$p.value < .05))
```

Most of the differences seem likely to be due to `styler`, as we are using the
`knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy="styler")`
option in the book. I still don't understand why it would behave differently on the two machines, though.  The includegraphics difference must be due to something else.

As we get down to the final layout of this book, it's difficult to do the work on it when we can't get the same results on different machines.  Any guesses about other environmental factors that might be affecting our build would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help @yihui, here's more info as requested...

```
> xfun::session_info(c('rmarkdown', 'bookdown', 'styler'))
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7, RStudio 1.4.1106

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  backports_1.2.1   base64enc_0.1.3   bookdown_0.22     cli_2.5.0        
  crayon_1.4.1      digest_0.6.27     ellipsis_0.3.2    evaluate_0.14    
  fansi_0.4.2       glue_1.4.2        graphics_4.0.5    grDevices_4.0.5  
  highr_0.9         htmltools_0.5.1.1 jsonlite_1.7.2    knitr_1.33       
  lifecycle_1.0.0   magrittr_2.0.1    markdown_1.1      methods_4.0.5    
  mime_0.10         pillar_1.6.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   purrr_0.3.4      
  R.cache_0.15.0    R.methodsS3_1.8.1 R.oo_1.24.0       R.utils_2.10.1   
  rematch2_2.1.2    rlang_0.4.11      rmarkdown_2.8     rprojroot_2.0.2  
  stats_4.0.5       stringi_1.6.2     stringr_1.4.0     styler_1.4.1     
  tibble_3.1.2      tinytex_0.31      tools_4.0.5       utf8_1.2.1       
  utils_4.0.5       vctrs_0.3.8       withr_2.4.2       xfun_0.23        
  yaml_2.2.1       

Pandoc version: 2.13
```

The results of `session_info` were identical (checked with diff) on both machines, the only exception being that my other computer is running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

`renv` sounds like we should get it going, thanks for the tip.

I started with a diff of the `.tex` files and I'm pretty confident that the only differences in those files come from the differences in the `.md` files.  They're all issues with `Tok` commands having extra space and line breaks here and there (along with the includegraphics change).  Trying to diff the tex log files is challenging because the line numbers don't match so every underfull hbox warning shows up in the diff, but I've looked through them and apart from the line numbering mismatches the logs match.

One more guess - is it possible this could be caused by something in `.Rproj.user`?  That's in the `.gitignore` file so it's potentially out of sync between the two machines.

Another update: I turned off `styler` and that eliminated all differences except the `includegraphics` change.  We use a lot of graphics and the only two that cause this difference are the ones where we specify `out.height`.  Usually we set `out.width`.

Comment: Would you please provide the output of `xfun::session_info(c('rmarkdown', 'bookdown', 'styler'))` from the two machines? BTW, if you want to work with the same versions of R packages, you may consider using tools like [**renv**](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/) for your project, instead of manually managing the package versions.

Comment: You might want to check if your are using the same versions of your latex packages. Add `keep_tex: true` to your header and make a diff of the .log files. And if you are at it, make a diff of the .tex files as well - if they are identical you can rule out all the markdown, pandoc end stuff

Comment: "having extra space and line breaks here and there " can be totally enough to result in a couple of pages difference in the final document. Test with the exact same input, only if this result in different pdfs, investigating further is worth the effort

Comment: This looks strange for {styler}. Maybe a caching issue? You can empty the {styler} cache with `styler::cache_clear()`. Also, check the cache location with `styler::cache_info()` to make sure your cache is version specific. Check the R option `styler.cache_name` to see if you are using a custom cache. Maybe {knitr} also has a cache it uses where invalidation was not triggered, I don't know.